# How can we call the primesieve C library from Julia?

Tags: c, julia, primes

The fastest method for generating primes in python is to use `primesieve-python`, a binding to the C/C++ library `primesieve` (http://primesieve.org/). You can iterate over primes with

```
import primesieve
it = primesieve.Iterator()
prime = it.next_prime()
prime = it.next_prime()
```

We can call this python library from Julia using `PyCall`. However, I expect it would be quicker to iterate over primes by calling the C function `primesieve_next_prime` directly. How easy is this to do, for people with no knowledge of C?

Comment: Have you tried follow this part of the documentation? http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/calling-c-and-fortran-code/

Comment: That was my first port of call. But I couldn't easily match the examples to the definition at http://primesieve.org/api/primesieve__iterator_8h.html#a4512ff6ce19e25042f07fe1337bb0dbe I got the impression that - unlike Julia in general - calling C code was something for experienced programmers only.

Comment: Making a wrapper to a C API from Julia is fairly easy, and it's not just for "experienced" programmers (You don't even really know C to be able to do it, for the most part, you just need to understand what the equivalent Julia types are).  Which parts of wrapping the C API gave you problems?

Comment: The examples are passing Julia things (numbers, strings) to a C function. Here we need to set up a C thing `primesieve_iterator`, initialise it in C, then run the C function `primesieve_next_prime` on that C thing, before returning the result (a number) to Julia: see [example](http://primesieve.org/api/primesieve_iterator_8c-example.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead and wrapped it, and translated that example to Julia.
This was just quick & dirty (it doesn't use the Julia iterator interface, which would be better, I just made it match the C API)
A few points: because there is C allocated memory involved, I set up a finalizer so that if the iterator object goes out of scope and gets garbage collected, the C allocated memory will still get freed.  I also made it so that it could be explicitly freed (and protected against trying to free the memory twice)
Also, the module and each function has a doc string (I should have put on for the type as well).  It uses `Ref` to pass a pointer to the structure to C.

When I ran it, I got the following result:

```
julia> @time example()
Sum of the primes below 10^10 = 2220820311119164929
   5.836645 seconds (609 allocations: 16.324 KB)
```

I hope that's the correct result!

Here is my quick wrapping of just the iterator interface:

```
"""
    Wrapper for primesieves library
    Copyright 2016 Scott Paul Jones
    MIT Licensed
"""
module PrimeSieves

export PrimeSieveIterator, skipto, next, previous, free

const global psilib = "libprimesieve.dylib"

type PrimeSieveIterator
    i::Csize_t
    last_idx::Csize_t
    primes::Ptr{UInt64}
    primes_pimpl::Ptr{UInt64}
    start::UInt64
    stop::UInt64
    stop_hint::UInt64
    tiny_cache_size::UInt64
    is_error::Cint
    function PrimeSieveIterator()
        piter = new(0,0,C_NULL,C_NULL,0,0,0,0,0)
        ccall((:primesieve_init, psilib), Void, (Ref{PrimeSieveIterator},), piter)
        finalizer(piter, free)
        piter
    end
end

""" Free all memory """
function free(piter::PrimeSieveIterator)
    # Make sure it isn't freed twice
    if piter.primes != C_NULL
        ccall((:primesieve_free_iterator, psilib), Void, (Ref{PrimeSieveIterator},), piter)
        piter.primes = C_NULL
        piter.primes_pimpl = C_NULL
    end
    nothing
end
""" Set the primesieve iterator to start """
skipto(piter::PrimeSieveIterator, start::Integer, stop_hint::Integer) =
    ccall((:primesieve_skipto, psilib), Void,
          (Ref{PrimeSieveIterator}, UInt64, UInt64), piter, start, stop_hint)

""" Get the next prime """
function Base.next(piter::PrimeSieveIterator)
    (piter.i-1) >= piter.last_idx &&
        ccall((:primesieve_generate_next_primes, psilib), Void, (Ref{PrimeSieveIterator},), piter)
    unsafe_load(piter.primes, piter.i += 1)
end

""" Get the previous prime """
function previous(piter::PrimeSieveIterator)
    if piter.i == 0
        ccall((:primesieve_generate_previous_primes, psilib),
              Void, (Ref{PrimeSieveIterator},), piter)
    else
        piter.i -= 1
    end
    unsafe_load(piter.primes, piter.i + 1)
end

end
```

The example code would be:

```
using PrimeSieves

function example()
    pit = PrimeSieveIterator()
    sum = UInt64(0)
    # iterate over the primes below 10^10
    while (prime = next(pit)) < UInt64(10000000000)
        sum += prime
    end
    free(pit)
    println("Sum of the primes below 10^10 = ", sum)
end

example()
```

Comment: This is excellent, and a real improvement on the existing prime functionality in Julia. I wonder if the licence on the C library is consistent with this being used as a Julia package?

Comment: I'm glad you like it!  The source is licensed under BSD 2-clause, which looks almost identical to the MIT license. I just did this as a mental exercise to show that wrapping C code is not hard in Julia, I'm not a mathematician.  If you think it really is useful, I can add it as a package (should probably get the rest of the API wrapped though!)

Comment: The good news: your code is 20x faster than the next best prime iterator (which is, strangely, the simple code of increment `n` and run `isprime(n)`).

Comment: The bad news: it misses some (albeit very few) primes, the first being 587 (it skips straight to 593). The python (C++) wrapper of `primesieve` doesn't do this, nor does the command line version of `primesieve`. I've no idea why this might be. Does the underlying C library do the same?

Comment: OK, it must be an off-by-one problem, when reloading the primes buffer. I'll try to fix it ASAP.

Comment: On further investigation, there seem to be bugs in the primesieve iterator implementation (probably the Python wrapper doesn't use that API). I've managed to make it work in the forward direction, but the previous entry point returns a structure that's not consistent with the structure returned when going in the forward direction.  I'll try to report the bug to the appropriate people.

Comment: OK, I've updated the Julia code, let me know if you see any other issue.

Comment: Great, lots faster, and working! There was a [discussion](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/11594) about improving the prime sieve in Julia, that is currently part of the base code. The discussion seemed to move towards its instead being part of a separate primes package. I think packaging this up would be a relative easy step towards that aim.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112520/discussion-between-u003f-and-scott-jones).